# add a specific value in an arraylist to the another arraylist

Tags: arrays, arraylist, nullpointerexception, hashset

there! I am working on my school work and I am a Java beginner. I am writing a program that has an ArrayList called petshop. the petshop is consisted by object residents.

the object residents has fields like name, birthday, postcode and pet (the pet that the resident has). Following is an example of the object Residents:
name Jan
birthday 11/11/1991
postcode 2222
pet dog cat pig

I am writing a method to find out how many different kinds of pet does the record cover. What I am thinking is add the pet record from petshop into a new String Array Pet, and clean the duplicate value.
here is my code:

```
public void addpets() {
        Set<String>cleanpets = new HashSet<>();
        
    
        for(int i=0; i<petshop.size();i++)
        {           
            String[]pet = petshop.get(i).getPetown().split("");
     
            for(int j=0; j<pet.length; j++)
            {
                pets.add(pet[j]);
            }
        }   
    
            cleanpets.addAll(pets);
            pets.clear();
            pets.addAll(cleanpets);
        }
```

Pets is the new String ArrayList that I have initialise in the same class. When I run the whole program, the console always shows Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException with the line: pet = petshop.get(i).getPetown().split("");

I don't understand where is wrong. Or is there another way to do it?

## I know what the problem is now. Because if the residents has only one pet, the String[]pet = petshop.get(i).getPetown().split(""); won't be work.

Comment: Is `petshop` defined outside of this method? Usually `NullPointerException` gets thrown when something is undefined and you're trying to access it. In this case, it might be because you're trying to reference the variable `petshop` but it's not passed as a parameter or created anywhere in the scope of this method.

Comment: Hi, Tyler, I have checked and the pet shop is defined inside this class.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your other methods, it's difficult to see what's wrong, but my guess is when you're putting it into the array, since that's the line that's throwing the exception.

You're initiating the array as `String[]pets;` but you don't use the `new` keyword to actually make the array or specify its size; all you've got is the name `pet`. When you do that with a variable that's not a primitive type (look this up if you don't know what it is), you're essentially creating a reference. But, your reference (named `pet` currently) isn't putting to anything because you don't set it to anything. To fix this, say `String[] pet = new String[insert_size];` so that `pet` actually references an array that can hold `String` variables.

Comment: thank you for answering. I have tried this way, but it still don't work.